# How do I upsert in sqlite using diesel?

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-diesel

I am migrating rust application from Postgres to Sqlite. But I've got an issue with upsert

Following code

```
diesel::insert_into(dialogs_table)
            .values(dialog)
            .on_conflict(user_id_column)
```

gives me this:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `on_conflict` found for struct InsertStatement in the current scope
```

I find this strange because it was working for Postgres. What could be the possible solution to use upsert here?

Comment: What is `upsert` please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html (This is one reason why I prefer writing my own SQL to using an ORM or some other query generator; you can actually use all the database features you want instead of being restricted to just what the ORM layer understands)

Comment: @Shawn Thank you - I had not heard of that.

Comment: @Shawn that seems like throwing the baby with the bathwater. Pretty much all ORMs or query builder have escape hatches allowing writing raw SQL. [diesel certainly does](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/fn.sql_query.html). And of course the situation here is DB migration / cross-DB support, which is absolute hell to do by hand using raw sql everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could be the possible solution to use upsert here?

Support for sqlite upserts was merged [in early 2020](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/pull/1884) (after a very long and rather gruelling PR process), but it apparently includes breaking changes so my understanding's it'll only be available in Diesel 2.0.

Therefore your possibly solutions are:

1. don't use upserts
2. [perform your query by hand](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/fn.sql_query.html)
3. [use git diesel](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/1854#issuecomment-828407144)

Comment: Yeah, I've already migrated to a git diesel and it is all fine, thanks for your response :)